# Backup uploaded and extracted, but at 99% of DB restoration, I am getting errors while WP migrating (plugin "All-in-one-migration")

Tags: python, php, wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2

I created an [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance and installed PHP, [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), Apache and WordPress. I configured the below four files:

1. `sudo vim /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`

   - Change maximum file size upload limitation.
   - Upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit and max_file_uploads
2. `sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

   .htaccess by (<Directory /var/www/>  AllowOverride All)
3. `sudo vim /var/www/html/wp-config.php`

   Set you DB credential and define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
4. `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   Set password authentication

   ```
   Plugin ---- All-IN-ONE-MIGRATION
   Stage >> File Import 100%
            extract 100%
            Getting error in 99% of DB restoration

   GET https://35myip6/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ai1wm_status&ai1wm_import=1&secret_key=x2huyD7Y84n0&_=1704795105444 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

   load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.4.2:2
   POST http://35.myip---18/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ai1wm_import&ai1wm_import=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
   ```

[Image of progress ("99%")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIKLb.png)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please try out this version of the All in One Migration plugin to import wp backup? Link: https://github.com/shameemreza/all-in-one-wp-migration

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering during the WordPress migration seems to involve connection refusal when attempting to import the database using the All-in-One WP Migration plugin. There are a few things you can check and adjust to resolve this issue:

**1. Check the IP Address or Domain Setting:**
Ensure that the WordPress settings (Settings -> General) have the correct URL set (especially if it's an IP address-based access or a domain-based access). It should match the one where your WordPress instance is hosted.

**2. Server Firewall and Security Group Settings:**
Make sure that your server's firewall or any security groups associated with your EC2 instance allow incoming and outgoing traffic on the necessary ports. For WordPress, it's usually port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS).

**3. WordPress Permalinks:**
Sometimes issues occur due to permalink settings. Go to Settings -> Permalinks in your WordPress admin dashboard and try changing the permalink structure. Then, attempt the migration again.

**4. Plugin/Theme Conflict:**
Temporarily disable other plugins and switch to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty-One) to rule out any conflicts that might be causing the issue during migration.

**5. Temporary Memory Increase:**
Increase PHP memory temporarily in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

**6. .htaccess file:**
Make sure you have the correct .htaccess settings in your WordPress directory. Try resetting it by going to Settings -> Permalinks and saving changes (WordPress will automatically update the .htaccess file).

**7. Error Logging:**
Enable WordPress debugging in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

**8. Plugin Reinstall or Update:**
Reinstall the All-in-One WP Migration plugin or update it to the latest version to ensure compatibility with your WordPress version.

**9. Database Size:**
Check if the database size is too large for your server to handle during import. If so, try breaking the export file into smaller parts for import.

**10. Server Logs:**
Check your Apache server logs (/var/log/apache2/error.log) and PHP logs (/var/log/php/error.log or as specified in your PHP configuration) for more detailed error messages that might provide insights into the cause of the 500 Internal Server Error.

Remember to make backups before making changes and proceed with caution while modifying server configurations or files. If the issue persists, the server logs are often helpful in diagnosing the root cause of the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy